# Group homomorphisms .

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $\alpha\colon G → H$ is a homomorphism of groups and $g \in G$ has finite order.

I want to show that $\alpha(g)$ has finite order and that the order of $\alpha(g)$ divides the order of g

What I have done is say that $ord(g)=n$ so $g^n=e(G)$ so:

$$α(g)α(g)^{-1}=e(H)=α(gg^{-1})=α(e(G))=α(g^n)=α(g)^n$$

but this gives me that the order of $\alpha(g)$ is n and the second part of the question is asking: If $\alpha$ is injective, show that the order of $\alpha(g)$ is equal to the order of $g$. So this cannot be true for $\alpha$ unless it is injective.

Comment: Please [use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If $x^n=e$, that does not tell you that the order of $x$ **is** $n$. It tells you that the order of $x$....

Comment: ("If $\alpha$ is injective, show that `X` happens" does not mean "`X` can only happen if $\alpha$ is injective." That would be the implication going the *other* way)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so how is the proof for (ii) different from the first part?

Comment: The first part just shows that $\alpha(g)^n=e$, not that $n$ is the smallest one that works. If you additionally know that $\alpha$ is injective, and that $\alpha(g)^k=e$, then you know that $\alpha(g^k)=e$, so...

Comment: oh, I've got this now. Thank you!